# i am getting GraphQLError: Syntax Error: Expected Name

Tags: node.js, graphql

hi i am new to grapqhl and below is my schema code:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

app.use(
    '/graphql',
    graphqlHttp({
        schema: buildSchema(`
            type: RootQuery {
                events: [String!]!
            }

```
        type: RootMutation {
            createEvent(name: String): String
        }

        schema {
            query: RootQuery
            mutation: RootMutation
        }
    `),
    rootValue: {
        events: () => {
            return ['events','cooking','real'];
        },

        createEvent: (args) => {
            const eventName = args.name;
            return eventName
        }
    },
    graphiql: true
})
```

);

Comment: can you provide your graphql mutation you write in probably the graphql playground ?

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is not valid. There is no colon after the `type` keyword.

Comment: thanx that was the issue